# JQuery behaving differently in Firefox and Chrome/Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code which places images in columns(not my code but modified). I just added a script for infinite scroll so to retain the previous order of the images, I have them nested in a page div and so I iterate through page div and then go ahead to iterate through each image within the page. The odd thing here is that Firefox seems to place the images right but chrome and safari just mess the placement up with duplicate additions. Any one got any ideas why?

```
var colCount = 0;
var colWidth = 225;
var margin = 10;
var spaceLeft = 0;
var windowWidth = 0;
var blocks = [];

$(function(){
  $(window).resize(setupBlocks);
});

function setupBlocks() {
  windowWidth =  $("#container").outerWidth();
  blocks = [];
  // Calculate the margin so the blocks are evenly spaced within the window
  colCount = Math.floor(windowWidth /(colWidth + margin*2));
  spaceLeft = (windowWidth - ((colWidth*colCount)+(margin*(colCount-1)))) / 2;
  for(var i=0;i<colCount;i++){
    blocks.push(margin);
  }
  positionBlocks();

}

function positionBlocks() {
 $('.page').each(function(i){
  $(this).children('.block').each(function(j){
    var min = Array.min(blocks);
    var index = $.inArray(min, blocks);
    var leftPos = (index * (colWidth + margin));
    $(this).css({
      'left':(leftPos + spaceLeft) + 'px',
      'top':min+'px'
    });
    blocks[index] = min+$(this).outerHeight() + margin;
  });
  }); 
}

$(window).scroll(function(){
  if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
  //$('div#loadmoreajaxloader').show();
  $.ajax({
    url: "/more",
    success: function(html){
      if(html){
        $("#container").append(html);
        setupBlocks()
        //$('div#loadmoreajaxloader').hide();
      }else{
        $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').html('<center>No more posts to show.</center>');
      }
    }
  });
}
});
```

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle for this?

Comment: Have you done any debugging?

Comment: You're inserting a `<center>` element? That thing has been deprecated a long time ago.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas So are a lot of things, but they still work...

Comment: @Ian I don't understand your comment. Are you implying that it's OK to use deprecated features?